# How do you achieve this colorful chrome effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects

I've been trying to figure out how to get this shaped chrome effect, it’s really clean and I’d love to play with it in Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: In my opinion that is not a "chrome effect", which is mainly a reflective material. This is either refraction (glass) or diffraction (an interference pattern).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd use a Bevel and Emboss effect, combined with a Satin effect, and a curves Adjustment layer to modify the colours.

It's difficult to get the colours exactly the same, since I have no idea what specific curves were used.  But the example below should give you a basic idea of how to get something similar.

[image]