# How can I achieve this type of texture with type?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I know how tu use bevel and emboss but it seems to be more than that … Thanks for ur answers !!

[image]

Comment: Please share what you have tired.

Comment: [My answer here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115756/how-do-you-achieve-this-colorful-chrome-effect/115758#115758), although not specifically for type, could be applied to type nevertheless.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks !! not so easy to get that kind of colours with curves but i'll give it a try !