# How to create embossed text in Cinema 4D. See example

Tags: 3d, cinema4d

How to create embossed text in Cinema 4D. See example[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't think it looks like something created in 3D software, more like a chrome effect created in Photoshop, from a simple 2D graphic. Have a look at my answer to this question: [How do you achieve this colorful chrome effect](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115756/how-do-you-achieve-this-colorful-chrome-effect)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you achieve this colorful chrome effect?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115756/how-do-you-achieve-this-colorful-chrome-effect)

Answer (score 1):

In Cinema4D you'd load the shape file as a spline object (or write your Text in a Text-object, which essentially is also a spline object.

You put the spline object in a Extrude-Nurbs and change the nurbs' caps attributes to have a fillet.

Answer (score 1):

This is done in Photoshop.

Using the emboss effect,
cracking up the curves, then applying a gradient map.

The flares / glares are then added in after.

Comment: Well. can you please explain your answer better? For example by adding screenshots showing the way to create the given effect? And explain in your words, what one have to do ...