# How to create texture like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, texture

How can I create texture like this one on the font? 
https://www.instagram.com/p/B-pXX3pBg35/
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What have you tried? What has failed?

Comment: Hello, @BillyKerr. Actually I don't even know how to start or in which direction should I move, so any your suggestion will be helpful

Comment: In that case, I suggest you look at tutorials for making bevel and emboss effects, and tutorials for adding textures. There are lots on youtube. There are even a few related questions here if you search for them. [This one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115756/how-do-you-achieve-this-colorful-chrome-effect/115758#115758) covers making bevels on graphics.