# Best way to create these abstract shapes (in Ai / Ps)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, vector, path, pen-tool

Note that I'm not referring to the shiny / chrome look, just the actual shapes themselves.

It's hard to even find the words to describe them — I'd say tangled-looking / tribal-esque shapes.

I can't quite tell if they were made in 3D software, but I feel that is irrelevant.

Do I just need to bite the bullet and sketch them out before then drawing them manually with the pen tool (say in Illustrator)... or is there an easier way?

I did try to experiment with the image trace function in Illustrator, using stock photos of plant roots... but the results were a bit sloppy.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you achieve this colorful chrome effect?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115756/how-do-you-achieve-this-colorful-chrome-effect/115758#115758)

Comment: @BillyKerr see the first line of my question

Comment: I see, then just draw them with the Pen Tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Illustrator. I would start with the Pen Tool, and draw a kind of random squiggly shape, then use the Warp Tool to add complexity.

Repeat several times with overlapping shapes until you have a tangled mess.

A quick example

[image]

Comment: Oooh I had no idea the warp tool even existed... thanks

Comment: @user19860331 - there are several other distortion tools that could be used under that tool group too.  Check them out - crystallize, pucker, bloat, twirl, scallop, wrinkle.

Comment: That's great thanks